# HAVING, JOINS, GROUP BY MySQL

Tags: mysql

I formulated the following query:

How to gather the names of all titles which contain at least nine tracks.

I thought that I could use a select statement having and group by and an inner join in the following way:

```
select ti.title from titles ti
inner join tracks tr on (ti.titleid = tr.titleid)
where tr.tracknum having count >=9;
```

The MySQL Query Engine is throwing me an error: Unknown column 'tr.tracknum' in 'having clause'. Is there way I can revise my query to produce a result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ti.title from titles ti
inner join tracks tr on (ti.titleid = tr.titleid) 
GROUP BY title 
having count(title) >=9;
```

HAVING refers to columns in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

```
select ti.title 
from titles ti
inner join tracks tr on ti.titleid = tr.titleid
group by ti.title
having count(*) >=9;
```